# Organization Chart with Azure AD users or User Information list users in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, orgchart, getorgchart, sharepoint-userprofile

I need the Orgchart web part which gets data from Azure AD users or User Information List in SharePoint online.

It needs to display all staff from top to bottom of the organization.

Is SharePoint provide Orgchart or do we need to develop it?

Can anyone help me with the same?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:
using SharePoint online modern organization chart webpart
using SharePoint online Space feature organization chart
using many organization chart app in Microsoft AppSource
using custom organization chart webpart from SharePoint 3rd party companies

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=sharepoint

https://adoption.microsoft.com/sample-solution-gallery/pnp-sp-dev-spfx-web-parts-react-organization-chart

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-org-chart-to-a-sharepoint-space-401998fd-e8d3-4a10-b716-fca25ed778a8

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have created organization chart using PrimeNG library